# preg_match to find postal address

Tags: php, preg-match

I need your help regarding a `preg_match`.
I try to extract from a string, a `postal address`. I use `preg_match` to do this like :

```
$search  = "blablablabla 10 rue Robert Schuman 75000 Paris blablablabla";
$preg=preg_match("'[0-9] rue (.*) ([0-9]{5})'s" ,$search,$infos);
print_r($infos);
```

This give me :

```
0 rue Robert Schuman 75000
```

How can i find `10` instead of just `0`?

Thks !

Comment: Try adding a `+` after `[0-9]`, it works wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $search  = "blablablabla 10 rue Robert Schuman 75000 Paris blablablabla";
    $preg = preg_match("/\d+ rue (.*) ([0-9]{5})/s" ,$search,$infos);
    print_r($infos);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10 rue Robert Schuman 75000
    [1] => Robert Schuman
    [2] => 75000
)
```

Comment: @VincentMallet Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: You can accept and upvote the answer how helped you the most and solved your problem!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$preg=preg_match("'[0-9]* rue (.*) ([0-9]{5})'s" ,$search,$infos);
```

Will match any number of digits.

ETA If you want one or more digits:

```
$preg=preg_match("'[0-9]+ rue (.*) ([0-9]{5})'s" ,$search,$infos);
```